# How can we save the trees in our historical garden from dying?

Tags: trees, diagnosis, plant-health, diseases, pines

Our historical building is located in a big garden with 2700 pine trees in Khaf city, Iran, and about 300 trees have died. Is there anything we can do to save these huge trees?

Khaf city has warm weather and strong wind, but the strong winds are not a problem.

[image]

Comment: I think you should contact some local expert to look for the trees. 300 trees are many trees, so probably some virus or other disease, which requires local check, and probably local cures (cures that depends on local climate and environment).

Comment: what's the lifespan and height of the trees, there may be a connection. As you say they're pines, they seem closely planted, so the lower branches are useless, and would die off.

Comment: Have you had a drought? Sometimes it'll take pines 3 or 4 years to succumb to a one year drought. As far as I know, there's nothing to be done besides replacement. There's a park here that lost 1000 pines to a drought. I'm certain they'd have saved them if they could.

Comment: Thank you. yes the local expert have visited this garden. but they say u should cut this died trees and no way to save this trees.
as you know we have historical site and if we cut those died trees out view was be disturbed.

Comment: When pine needles get brown the tree is dead. In the piney woods of TX that size tree would be called saplings. Here, pine bark beetles will attack and kill closely placed trees such as shown.

Answer (score 1):

In the historic context, while the buildings can be held in a static condition over time, a landscape is dynamic, constantly changing. Considering the existing planting we can be aware that the depth of soil available for trees can vary considerably between locations. During a drought those on thin soil and in competition with close neighbours will suffer more and will often die out, leaving those in deeper soil to survive.

To maintain a visual barrier over time requires planning. One solution might be to have a multi-year long term plan which calls for replacement trees planted alternately every five years or so, with the tallest deliberately removed, along with roots, and small trees replanted, in their turn, to eventually take over as the tallest. If you have some leeway in choice of plant materials, choose those species that fit the plan most effectively.